# How to make my button state selected even after i change View Controller and come back. Swift

Tags: ios, swift, tableview

So my problem is that i have 2 View Controllers, VC1 and VC2, i go from VC1 to VC2 through a button, in VC2 i have a table view in which i have 3 cells containing buttons. In VC2 when i click button an Api is called, I want to make it so that when i click button in VC2 it gets highlighted and if i go back to VC1 and come back to VC2 again it shows the button still selected. I have tried using many things but it does not work. Sorry for not posting code for certain reasons I am unable to share my code.

Comment: You need to maintain the button state in User Defaults.

Comment: How do I do that @HammerClass

Comment: *"go from VC1 to VC2 through a button"* ... do you mean you're in a navigation controller and you **push** to VC2? Do you need to save the "highlighted" state of the button in VC2 if the user comes back to your app in a week? or, only while the app is being used - and the next time everything is back to "starting state"?

Comment: If you just want to keep the "highlighted" state of the button in VC2. 1. you can save its state in VC1 through Delegate in VC2； 2. you can make use of ``User Defaults``